# Convert single line if statement in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to convert this function in TSQL but I don't know how I can replace the || operator in TSQL. Does MS SQL has a equivalent for || ?

```
  private bool intersects(DateTime r1start, DateTime r1end,
                        DateTime r2start, DateTime r2end)
    {
        return (r1start == r2start)
            || (r1start > r2start ?
                r1start <= r2end : r2start <= r1end);
    }
```

Does the  syntax in T-SQL is ok?

```
IF((@r1start=@r2start)or(@r1start>@r2start))
BEGIN
    IF(@r1start<=@r2end)
        return 1;
    ELSE
        return 0;
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    IF(@r2start<=@r1end)
        return 1;
    ELSE
        return 0;
END
```

Comment: Why not simply `r1start >= r2start`?

Comment: I have found this snippet on the web, I just want to rewrite this function in t-sql

Comment: SQL Server does NOT do short-circuiting, there is no equivalent of `||` in SQL Server. The only thing that come close is the `OR` operator.

Comment: Can we see your attempt of this logic in TSQL as a starting point?

Comment: @db_brad: just edited

Comment: The `CASE- WHEN` statement supports short circuit evaluation.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43352/does-sql-server-case-statement-evaluate-all-conditions-or-exit-on-first-true-con

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simplify the whole thing.  This should find if r1 and r2 intersect:

```
IF (@r1start <= @r2end AND @r1end >= @r2start)
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent operator in TSQL is simply just the word `or`.

Comment: The difference between | and || ?

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you mean by | as it is not covered in your question.

Comment: | is a bitwise or and || is a logical or.

Comment: In C# Logical OR= || and | = bitwise OR. It's one of my first experience in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server 2012, you can use IIF

```
declare @ret int

select @ret = iif(@r1start <= @r2end and @r1end >= @r2start, 1, 0)

return @ret
```